# Can I use "into there" in context?

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality-in-context

Is it a correct sentence? Can I use "into there" in this context?

> "We travel through the time into the black hole, let's come back home into there."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not quite correct, breaking it into two parts

> We can travel through time *in that* black hole...
>   We can travel through time *with that* black hole...

assuming you are already *at home* and want to come back at a different time

> let's come back home *through / in* there.

if you are on the other side of the galaxy and want to get home

> let's go back home *through / in* there.

One problem is that we do not know where a Black Hole leads to and current understanding of references (to, from, into) in Newtonian space might change once we do know what happens in relativistic space.

It's like the joke about twins in the womb

> Twin 1: What is that?
>   Twin 2: It's a birth canal.
>   Twin 1: Where does it go?
>   Twin 2: We don't know, no one's ever come back.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But what if I want to come back at a different time. Should I say:
"Let's travel back in time to my little Earth" or "on my Earth" or "into my Earth"?

And what if I'm on the other side of galaxy or another dimension. May I say:
"Let's go back home in my Universe"

Comment: You probably want to use "to" in both cases. You want to travel "to" a destination in either time or space. If you say "into my Earth" you will wind up someplace between the surface and the core. If you say "back in time *on* my Earth, you may mean *specifically* back in *Earth-time on Earth* as opposed to [stardate time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardate) though both would be "back in time" in an absolute sense. "Let's go back home *to* my Universe".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not in that particular sentence:

> We can travel through time by using that black hole! Let's *go* back home by traveling *through* there.

Although you can say:

> We can travel through time by using that black hole! If we go *into* there we will be home when we *come out* the other side.

(Leaving aside the fact that black holes actually have no "other side", of course  :)